# oData RIA PowerPivot Large Message Size

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ria, odata, excel-2010

I was playing with powerpivot to directly load 3 million rows from a sql database and performance is suprisingly good.

I tried generating a simple oData service by using vs2010 and silverlight RIA services and access that from powerpivot. Which works with small numbers of rows but blows up on the server if a single method tries to return 3 million rows. Not suprising I guess.

Ive often run into the message size issue with WCF and it is a real pain to configure transports to support larger sizes. Plus, ideally I dont want one big message but some sort of data packeting. Adding a layer of RIA and oData ontop of WCF seems to just make the idea of changing max message sizes even more convoluted.

Is there any support in the oData interface for a transport that will stream or packet the data returned from a method?

Is this a limitation of WCF/RIA or oData itself. Is it possible to use powerpivot connected to an oData source that returns millions of rows?

Anybody have ideas for better techniques of exposing large sets of data via WCF / RIA / oData ?

thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 2):

Found it! In the DataService<> class InitializeService method needed to use config.SetEntitySetPageSize.